# Button is not displaying completely

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to make a `button` in some HTML code for a small web app I made, however my `button` should say "ok" but the `button` itself is too small and doesn't display the "ok" completely.

Am I missing something for the `span`?

How can I increase the size of the `button` to be a bit larger and display all of the "ok"?

```html
<center>
  <br>
  <br>
  <span id="accept_button" style="display:none;"><button onclick="task.accept_choice();"><h3>ok</h3></button></span>
  <span id="next_button" style="display:none;"><button onclick="task.next_trial();"><h3>ok</h3></button></span>
</center>
```

Comment: Use CSS to style the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is because you are using `span` which is an inline element, so you had to set `display:block`, but I advise you to:

- use `div` to wrap the `button`
- you don't need nothing as child of `button` to wrap the text, because you can style the `button`
- don't use `center` tag because it is already deprecated, instead style an element using CSS

```html
<div id="accept_button">
  <button onclick="task.accept_choice();">ok</button>
</div>
<div id="next_button">
  <button onclick="task.next_trial();">ok</button>
</div>
```

---

**NOTE:** In **HTML5**, you can have `span` as parent of `h3`(same goes for `button`) but not in **HTML4**

[**HTML5:**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/h1.html#h1-context)

> **Permitted parent elements**
>
> any element that can contain flow elements, hgroup

**[7.1 Flow elements:](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.flow)**

> [phrasing elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing) or `a` or `p` or `hr` or `pre` or `ul` or `ol` or `dl` or `div` or `h1` or `h2` or `h3` or `h4` or `h5` or `h6` or `hgroup` or address or `blockquote` or `ins` or `del` or `object` or `map` or `noscript` or `section` or `nav` or `article` or `aside` or `header` or `footer` or `video` or `audio` or `figure` or `table` or `form` or `fieldset` or `menu` or `canvas` or `details`

And `span`/`button` are one of the [phrasing elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing)

Comment: so do i replace what I had with yours? also where in yours is the size defined? thanks!

Comment: is there a way to just physically make the button larger?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, setting `width` to button? can you provide a full fiddle to understand/help?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jo0tdf7p/#&togetherjs=EAEbfJ64oc is the whole code- and the button is just very tiny, I wanted to make this app for kids so I want like a fun large button! Sorry for my confusion!

Comment: you have to style the `button`, here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/0p6oe6ps/

Comment: OH Ok so that goes in the css file, not the html file! I understand now, wow thank you so much for helping me out! I am a bit of a newbie. :)

Comment: ya for styling use in CSS Files, don't use `center` or `font` tags html, they are deprecated